# C# window xp current user when using run as

Tags: c#, windows-xp

Is there any way to get the current user who used the run as command to run my applcation on windows xp? I have an application that must be run as an administrator but I need to be able to tell the user who started the application for putting short cuts on their desktop.

I have tried environment.getcurrentuser() and even doing a direct called to the windows api but unfortunately those only tell me the owner of the thread and not the currently logged in user.

Comment: `Environment.UserName` gets you user name who is logged on to machine. What else can you ask for?

Comment: In windows xp when using Environment.UserName it will give me back the user I ran the application as.

Comment: What this would give you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ??

Comment: @T.S. Tried that as well it just returned the user of the thread which is whoever I use "run as" as. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.getusername I found this to be more helpful than Microsofts document for using it though.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is correct behavior, what you get. If you "runAs" that the user name you should get

Comment: I think it is intended behavior is as well but it makes it hard to do what you can do on Windows 7/8 where you install short cuts to certain  users desktops. The work around that I used was to place short cuts on the public desktop so everyone gets it. Basically I was hoping for a way around just using the public desktop. I am going to go ahead and put this down as the answer but if anyone else comes up with a solution I will mark this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around that I used was to place short cuts on the public desktop so everyone gets it. Basically I was hoping for a way around just using the public desktop. I am going to go ahead and put this down as the answer but if anyone else comes up with a solution I will mark it as the answer.