# How do I get locale information about logged-in user from an administrator process on Windows XP in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, locale

A similar question got asked by others here at least twice already (see links below) but never properly answered, perhaps because it wasn't put the right way. Let me have a go:

I have a process running under the local account on Windows and I need locale information about the user who is logged into the interactive session if there is one or any interactive session if there is more than one.

I need to know the user's language and country settings and it has to work on all kinds of Windows starting XP Service Pack 3.

I very much appreciate your answers!

The previous related questions that didn't really get answered:

- [C# window xp current user when using run as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641707/c-sharp-window-xp-current-user-when-using-run-as)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778378/creating-a-process-as-logged-on-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the following way:

1. Enumerate logon sessions using `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions`
2. Call `LsaGetLogonSessionData` to get logged on user SID identifier.
3. Call `ConvertSidToStringSid` function to get a string representation of a sid.
4. Look up registry setting **HKEY_USERS[USER_SID_STRING]\Control Panel\International**

This key has all sorts of information needed, and looks like all listed WINAPI finctions are available starting at Windows XP.

So this should work.

Comment: I was trying to avoid groping in the registry directly and find a solution using just API calls instead. I thought I'd find an interactive user, start a process as this user and find all the locale info from inside this process. But that seems really complicated.

Comment: Logging on as a user w/o a password, that I suppose you don't know is not a good idea. I think it is possible if your account has "Act as a part of Operating system" privilege. I never did it myself though.